# Incorrect namespacing when creating new class in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

I have a problem in Phpstorm, that when I create a new class, it does not add 'App' to the namespace:

[image]

And when I add 'App' to the namespace it creates a folder with such a name:

[image]

Of course I can manually delete the folder name and it will be all ok. But is there a way I can avoid this?

For controllers/models and all other classes that I generate with `artisan` command that is not a problem, but for classes that I create in my apps domain folders it is really annoying having to manually add the namespace and deleting it from the folder.

Comment: Did you right-click the `app` folder when creating this new class? Or perhaps some issues with composer, you can do `composer dump-autoload` to see if anything changes

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Directories` -- you need to adjust your Source roots there (post a screenshot of what you have there at the moment)

Comment: So .. did you managed to resolve your issue?